# My code for max 1, max 2, max3 number is passing all test cases but one test case is showing MLE error can any one know how to pass that?

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array A of size N, you need to find its maximum, 2nd maximum, and 3rd maximum element.
Try solving it in O(N) per test case

**Input**

The first line of the input contains the number of test cases T.

For each test case, the first line of the input contains an integer N denoting the number of elements in the array A. The next line contains N (space separated) elements of A.

```
Constraints:
1 <= T <= 100
3 <= N <= 10^6
1 <= A[i] <= 10^9
```

***In my code, every test case is passing except one which is showing MLE.***

```
import java.io.*; // for handling input/output
import java.util.*; // contains Collections framework

// don't change the name of this class
// you can add inner classes if needed
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
                      // Your code here
                      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                      int size = sc.nextInt();
                   
                        while(size>0){
                           int n = sc.nextInt();
                          int myarray[] = new int [n];
                          for(int j=0; j<n;j++) {
                          myarray[j]= sc.nextInt();
                      }
                      printNumber(myarray);
                      size--;
                        }                
    }
    public static void printNumber(int [] myarray){
        int first=0;
        int second=0;
        int third=0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<myarray.length;i++){

            if (myarray[i] > first){
               third=second;
               second=first;
               first=myarray[i];
      }
      else if (myarray[i] > second){
         third = second;
         second = myarray[i];
      }
      else if (myarray[i] > third)
         third = myarray[i];
   }
   System.out.println(first+" "+second+" "+third);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is an *"MLE"*?

Comment: If "MLE" stands for "memory limit exceeded" then just don't create the array in the first place, just compare each of the inputs directly against your 3 variables (will require you to change your input loop to be combined with the comparison logic).

Comment: @UnholySheep, Thanks for the suggestions, I tried but still MLE showing.

Answer (score 0):

For the above problem, posted by me I was using a scanner so I think that's why it's showing MLE now I have used a buffered reader now, and it's working.

```
import java.io.*; // for handling input/output
import java.util.*; // contains Collections framework

// don't change the name of this class
// you can add inner classes if needed
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException {
                      // Your code here
                      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                      int size =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            
                        while(size>0){
                           int n =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                           String str[] = br.readLine().trim().split(" ");
                           printNumber(str);
                           size--;
                        }                
    }
    public static void printNumber(String [] myarray){
        int first=0;
        int second=0;
        int third=0;
        int num =0;
        for(int i=0;i<myarray.length;i++){
         num = Integer.parseInt(myarray[i]);
            if (num > first){
               third=second;
               second=first;
               first=num;
      }
      else if (num > second){
         third = second;
         second = num;
      }
      else if (num > third)
         third = num;
   }
   System.out.println(first+" "+second+" "+third);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.io.*; // for handling input/output
import java.util.*; // contains Collections framework

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int query=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i =0;i<query;i++){
                int n=sc.nextInt();
                int first = 0;
                int second=0;
                int third=0;
                for(int j =0;j<n;j++){
                        int curNum = sc.nextInt();
                        if (curNum > first){
                                 third=second;
                                 second=first;
                                 first=curNum;
                         }
                         else if (curNum > second){
                                 third = second;
                                 second = curNum;
                         }
                         else if (curNum > third)
                                 third = curNum;
                }
                System.out.println(first+" "+second+" "+third);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still Showing MLE by running your code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).